# Multiple file upload using input type file and PHP loop (without jQuery or Javascript)

Tags: php, html, web

I want to select more image files at a one time and upload as 1,2,3,4,... Like:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="imgs[]" id="imgs" multiple/> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["imgs"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";

      }
    else
      {

//I think loop goes here 
===================
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
===================

      }
?>
```

==================================================================

This is works...

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$count=1;
foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'] as $file) {
  echo '<li>' . $file . '</li>';

  copy($file, "uploads/" . $count.".jpg");
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $count.".jpg";
    $count++;
}
?>
```

this is works....

Comment: That's good ... you can add your own answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP build the `$_FILES` array in a strange (but consistent) way when you have multiple upload. Try creating this form with three file inputs:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="imgs[]" id="imgs" multiple /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then in the PHP code that receive your form, place only:

```
<?php print_r($_FILES); ?>
```

So you can see the `$_FILES` array structure. At this point all will be clear to you, and you will get yourself how to loop on it to save all uploaded images. Good luck ;)

Comment: ok... wufoo.com/html5/attributes/08-multiple.html see this article what are they telling ?? –

Comment: @SampathSriAnuradha Sorry, I already told you I was wrong ;) Basically, Udit answer is the PHP code I suggested you to "discover" yourself by looking at how PHP build the $_FILES array. ***Anyway `multiple` attribute seems to be not supported on IE < 10***.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your php code with this one :

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["imgs"]["name"]);$i++) 
{
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["imgs"]["name"][$i]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["imgs"]["name"][$i] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {

//I think loop goes here 
===================
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgs"]["tmp_name"][$i],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["imgs"]["name"][$i]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["imgs"]["name"][$i];
===================

      }
}
?>
```

Comment: **HTML Supports multiple tag . You don;t need to change your html code. just change the php code as above**

Comment: ok...
http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/08-multiple.html
see this article what are they telling ??

Comment: yes you can add multiple attribute to the file and yes you can also use foreach instead of for loop

Answer (score 0):

I have test the this code, it works, I forgot to answer it once I solved.

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

get data in PHP file as below.

```
<?php
 $count=1;
 foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'] as $file) {
   echo '<li>' . $file . '</li>';

   copy($file, "uploads/" . $count.".jpg");
   echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $count.".jpg";
   $count++;
 }
?>
```